# How to manage orientation in landscape and portrait using fragment

Tags: android

I create one example in Android 3.0 and I use the fragment in it. when I change the mode landscape to portrait or viseversa it give me the error as following but when I comment the fragment calling part it works smoothly as per my changes. for this I create layout-land folder and put may xml file with changes.

does any one have a hint or solution or example for match with this?

this is my fragment:

```
 <fragment 
            class="com.Organisemee.fragment.TaskListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/tasklistfrag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And this is error:

```
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Organisemee/com.Organisemee.OrganisemeeList}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #167: Error inflating class fragment
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3096)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:997)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #167: Error inflating class fragment
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:224)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1777)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at com.Organisemee.OrganisemeeList.onCreate(OrganisemeeList.java:73)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     ... 12 more
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.Organisemee.fragment.TaskListFragment did not create a view.
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4114)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
07-01 12:38:33.363: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(641):     ... 22 more
```

[image: this is mt layout folder image]

Comment: Screenshot of your resources folders would help

Comment: if you had your XML files named like this      activity_main.xml
     fragment_main.xml it would make your debugging a hell of a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to define a Fragment in XML Like This.

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/main_tasklist_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_viewmenu_layout"
android:layout_below="@+id/main_tasklist_outer">

 <fragment 
        class="com.Organisemee.fragment.TaskListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/tasklistfrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To Call the Fragment put this code in java file

```
            Fragment f = listFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ListFragft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ListFragft.replace(R.id.main_tasklist_layout, f);
            ListFragft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ListFragft.addToBackStack(null);
            ListFragft.commit();
```

This Works fine in change both orientation, landscape to portrait and vice versa.